# Sum of a geometric progression

Tags: summation

Just a very small query, I am currently looking at the solutions to a question, and the final step is:

$c$ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k$ = $\frac{cp}{1-p}$

Is this correct? I thought this formula only held when it went from k = 0 to infinity?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. And $\displaystyle c\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k=\frac c{1-p}\ne\frac{cp}{1-p}$.

Comment: The formula holds for any starting value for k, as long as the common ratio is between -1 and 1.